# How to create nested json objects with jackson

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jackson

I am using hibernate to query records of users from my db as shown:

```
String hql = "SELECT U FROM User U";
List<User> users = this.em.createQuery(hql).getResultList();
```

How do I convert the returned data into json as shown in the format below:

[image]

If no users are found I want my json to look as shown below:

[image]

I want to do some manipulation on the retrieved data before creating the json data. Therefore I want to avoid passing the list directly as shown below:

```
 String data = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(users);
```

Comment: How json looks if `usersFound` is `false`?

Comment: @KunLun no users found response has been added

Comment: Why not return the empty list of users if case usersFound=false?. I mean that `usersFound` is redundant in the response

Comment: Why don't you try DTO ?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object

Comment: Another solution, an easier way. You can try toString
@Override public String toString() { return "{" + "\"name\":\"" + name + '\"' + ", \"email\":\"" + email + '\"' + '}'; }

Comment: https://anotepad.com/notes/qicr8jeq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Jackson library, you should implement a simple DTO object containing a list of `User` / `UserDto`, a stub for an empty list with custom `msg` property and then create appropriate instance depending on available results.

Also you can set the order of properties in the generated JSON using `@JsonPropertyOrder` annotation.

```java
public class UserDto {
    private final String name;
    private final String email;

    public UserDto(String name, String email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getName() { return this.name; }
    public String getEmail() { return this.email; }
}

@JsonPropertyOrder({ "usersFound", "users" })
public class ListUserDto {
    private final List<UserDto> users;

    public ListUserDto(List<UserDto> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    public List<UserDto> getUsers() {
        return new ArrayList<>(users);
    }

    @JsonProperty("usersFound")
    public boolean isUsersFound() {
        return true;
    }
}

@JsonPropertyOrder({ "usersFound", "msg" })
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"users"})
public class EmptyListUserDto extends ListUserDto {
    public EmptyListUserDto() {
        super(Collections.emptyList());
    }

    public String getMsg() {
        return "No User Found";
    }

    @JsonProperty("usersFound")
    public boolean isUsersFound() {
        return false;
    }
}


// -------------
public ListUserDto buildUserListJson(List<User> users) {
//    String hql = "SELECT U FROM User U";
//    List<User> users = this.em.createQuery(hql).getResultList();

    if (null == users || users.isEmpty()) {
        return new EmptyListUserDto();
    }
    return new ListUserDto(
            users.stream()
                 .map(u -> new UserDto(u.getName(), u.getEmail()))
                 .collect(Collectors.toList())
    );
}
```

Test code:

```java
ObjectWriter writer = new ObjectMapper().writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter();

System.out.println(writer.writeValueAsString(buildUserListJson(
    List.of(new User("jack", "jack@mail.com"), new User("john", "john@mail.com"))
)));

System.out.println("null -> " + writer.writeValueAsString(buildUserListJson(null)));

System.out.println("empty -> " + writer.writeValueAsString(buildUserListJson(Collections.emptyList())));
```

Output:

```
{
  "usersFound" : true,
  "users" : [ {
    "name" : "jack",
    "email" : "jack@mail.com"
  }, {
    "name" : "john",
    "email" : "john@mail.com"
  } ]
}
null -> {
  "usersFound" : false,
  "msg" : "No User Found"
}
empty -> {
  "usersFound" : false,
  "msg" : "No User Found"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply build json step by step:

At first step I would recommend to create a method in `User` class which gives name and email of user as json.

```
public class User{

    ...
 
    public String getJsonUserEmail(){

        return "{\"name\": \"" + this.getName() + "\", " +
                "\"email\": \"" + this.getEmail() + "\"}"

    }

    ...

}
```

Than transform all users to json and build the last json.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String finalJson = "{";

    if(!users.isEmpty()){

        finalJson += "\"usersFound\": true, ";
                
        //transform every user to json
        //{"name": "name1", "email": "email1"}
        List<String> usersJson = users.stream()
                                      .map(e -> e.getJsonUserEmail())
                                      .collect(Collectors.toList());

        //join all jsons
        //{"name": "name1", "email": "email1"}, {"name": "name2", "email": "email2"}, ...
        String usersJsonJoin = String.join(", ", usersJson);

        finalJson += "\"users\": [" + usersJsonJoin + "]";

    }else{

        finalJson += "\"usersFound\": false, ";
        finalJson += "\"msg\": \"No users found\"";

    }

    finalJson += "}";

}
```

Comment: I suggest writing a method in User Object

Comment: @Tea, I was thinking at that, but in question is not mentioned the structure of `User` class, so I was thinking there are multiple fields than `name` and `email`.